# How to do something different when there is only one foreach result?

Tags: php, foreach

I've found and tried many examples but can't get this working so am obviously missing something basic sorry.

---

### 1. Problem

To fit more results on screen, we're outputting text expanders but only if there's more than one result.

---

### 2. Setup

This is what I've got so far...

```
<?php
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $count++;

        if ($count <= 1 ) {
            // First result
        } else {
            // The rest of the results
        }
    }
?>
```

But this simply isolates the first result (which is also useful).

---

### 3. Question

1. How do we determine if there's only one result overall, then output different markup for one result, and different markup for multiple results?

---

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Just... use [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to find out how many items are in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count($items)` to get the number of items in the array.

```
if(count($items) == 1) {
    //print 1 result
} else {
    //print multiple results
}
```

Comment: You don't need the second `if`. Either it's 0 and the `foreach` will just do nothing, or it's more than 1.